# How to set body class depending on state in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Here is my `index.html`:

```
...
<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
...
```

"my-app" is the selector of my bootstrap component. Here is template of bootstrap component:

```
...
@Component({
    selector: 'zen-app',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
...
```

It has many route states. In one of them I want to change body class. Is it possible? I use `router-deprecated` component

Answer (score 1):

Angolar2 currently doesn't provide anything to modify the DOM outside it's root component (except the title tag in head).

You can change the selector of the root component to `body`, inject `ElementRef` and modify according to your needs. 
In this case also `@HostBinding` can be used:

```
@HostBinding('class.someName') someName:boolean = true;
```

Alternatively you can just use direct DOM access to modify the `body` element.